# I want to make a command handler for embeds, but only one embed works and the others don't

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Ok, so
The command handler works, and I know it because I have 3 commands (2 are text only and one is an embed) that work. I've made this for embeds:

```js
case "menta":
          bot.commands.get('menta').execute(msg, args)
break;
```

I have other embeds that I've made in the same way as the one that works, but they do not work.
Here's the embed that works:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'menta',
    description: 'Info sulla menta',
    execute(msg, args) {
        const menta = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle('ERBE')
             .addField('Nome', 'Menta')
             .addField('Proprietá', 'Rompere gli incantesimi e acquisire forza mentale durante i periodi di difficoltà')
             .setColor('#66CD00');
             msg.channel.send(menta);
    },
};
```

That works by typing `mb! menta`.
I've made other 2, and those do not work. Here is one of them:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'alloro',
    description: 'Info sull alloro',
    execute(msg, args) {
        const menta = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle('ERBE')
             .addField('Nome', 'Alloro')
             .addField('Proprietá', 'Visioni psichiche e sogni, respinge la negatività e il male.')
             .setColor('#66CD00');
             msg.channel.send(alloro);
    },
};
```

I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\U\Desktop\discord bot\commands\aloe_vera.js:12
             msg.channel.send(alloro);
                              ^

ReferenceError: alloro is not defined
```

Sorry if it's a stupid question but I'm very very new in this type of thing lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error origin is pretty, simple, like the message says:

```js
execute(msg, args) {
        const menta = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle('ERBE')
             .addField('Nome', 'Alloro')
             .addField('Proprietá', 'Visioni psichiche e sogni, respinge la negatività e il male.')
             .setColor('#66CD00');
             msg.channel.send(alloro);
    }
```

Your newly created Embed is named menta, but you try to send one called alloro, just change the name of the const to alloro or send the menta emebed (either `const alloro = ...` or `msg.channel.send(menta)`).